# SphinxQL not allowing me to find/escape \

Tags: escaping, sphinx

I need to find the end of a html tag e.g. . I've tried various approaches like </body> and <\/body> and <\/body\> (based on various answers I've received elsewhere) yet nothing works; I either get an error thrown at me or zero results.

I'm wondering if I use regexp_filter to map  to TheEnd or some other term I can use to search against it will break anything? For instance if i use ZONES and have Body as a ZONE will that now break simply because I also map the end of the body zone to TheEnd for search purposes?

Comment: do you actully have / in your charset_table? If not, you can't match on it. But also if you using zones, suggests you may have html_strip enabled, which strips the html tags from being indexed.